# asp.net mvc 3 installed but no templates in vs 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, asp.net-mvc-3

when creating a new project
and 
no error messages in setup either !!

I have repeated the setup a few times to no avail

anyone else have the same issue or find an answer ?

Comment: I did not install any beta / RC version on this machine before

Comment: and i am trying to install using the full installer @ http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d2928bc1-f48c-4e95-a064-2a455a22c8f6

Comment: I have the same problem - no templates, no previous Beta/RC, full installer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have removed any previous Beta and RC versions before installing the ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM. Also try installing it by [downloading the full installer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d2928bc1-f48c-4e95-a064-2a455a22c8f6). Once installed you should see the new templates when creating a new web application in Visual Studio. The templates appear when creating a new web application and not new web site.

Comment: @Kumar, do you have a c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\ folder created after installing? Do you have the System.Web.Mvc v3 assembly in the GAC?

Comment: Yes the folder is created.... It didn't show in the gac using windows explorer, so i dropped it, no errors and no joy, tried a few times and then manually using gacutil, says success but not listing in windows explorer, however gacutil /l system.web.mvc shows ver 2.0 & 3.0 in the gac, few other peeks and pokes later, i tried adding a new project and voila, i see option for mvc3 app !

Comment: I have MVC4 Beta installed, tried using the web installer twice, it said 'sucessfully installed' but there were no folders or templates and nothing in program files. Downloading the full installer from the above link did the trick and I didn't have to remove MVC4 Beta. Thanks.

Comment: Hey! I am having the same problem, the folders are created but the options are not showing up, what to do now?

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you are targetting .NET 4

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I installed MVC 3 from the Windows Platform installer and it worked as expected, and templates were created.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this issue for a couple of hours until i solved the problem by these steps:

1. Uninstall SP1 for Visual Studio 2010
2. Repair Visual Studio 2010
3. Reinstall SP1 for VS2010

I hope you save some time by taking these steps.